# What do the numbers on a Git Diff header mean?

Tags: diff

Every time I run git diff, for each single changes I made, I get some sort of header with numbers, for example:

```
@@ -169,14 +167,12 @@ function Browser(window, document, body, XHR, $log) {.....
```

I wonder what does the four numbers mean? I guess -169 means that this particular line of code that follows was originally in line 169 but now is in 167? And what do 14 and 12 mean?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This *header* is called set of change, or hunk. Each hunk starts with a line that contains, enclosed in @@, the line or line range `from,no-of-lines` in the file before (with a `-`) and after (with a `+`) the changes. After that come the lines from the file. Lines starting with a `-` are deleted, lines starting with a `+` are added. Each line modified by the patch is surrounded with 3 lines of context before and after.

**An addition looks like this:**

```
@@ -75,6 +103,8 @@
 foo
 bar
 baz
+line1
+line2
 more context
 and more
 and still context
```

That means, in the original file before line 78 (= 75 + 3 lines of context) add two lines. These will be lines 106 (= 103 + 3 lines of context) through 107 after all changes.
Note the difference in `from` numbers (-75 vs +103), this means that there were other changes in this file before this particular hunk, that added 28 (103 - 75) lines of code.

**A deletion looks like this:**

```
@@ -75,7 +75,6 @@
 foo
 bar
 baz
-line1
 more context
 and more
 and still context
```

That means, delete line 78 (= 75 + 3 lines of context) in the original file. The unchanged context will be on lines 75 to 80 after all changes.
Note that `from` numbers in this hunk are equal (-75 and +75), this means that either there were no changes before this hunk, or amount of added and deleted lines in previous changes are the same.

**Finally, a change looks like this:**

```
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@
 foo
 bar
 baz
-red
+blue
 more context
 and more
 still context
```

That means, change line 73 (= 70 + 3 lines of context) in the file before all changes, which contains red to blue. The changed line is also line 73 (= 70 + 3 lines of context) in the file after all changes.

Comment: Short answer: 14 in your case is amount of lines in hunk before applying the changes, 12 - after.

Comment: The `no-of-lines` values may not be immediately obvious. The 'before' value is the sum of the 3 lead context lines, the number of `-` lines, and the 3 trailing context lines, while the 'after' values is the sum of 3 lead context lines, the number of `+` lines and the 3 trailing lines. In some cases there are additional intermediate context lines which are also added to those numbers. So the total number of lines displayed is commonly neither of the `no-of-lines` values!

Comment: There's a red herring in the first example of adding 2 lines: `@@ -75,6 +77,8 @@`. The 75 and 77 may confuse newbie to think that was related to adding 2 lines. Actually, a simpler example would just have `@@ -75,6 +75,8 @@`. The +77 would only be if there were other edits higher up that added a net of 2 lines.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Is there a reason for the 75/77 difference in the first example?

Comment: @Trengot Yes. I wanted to show that those numbers are not always equal. `from` numbers can be different in case if there were other changes before. I will update my answer with that.

Comment: Because this is such a great answer, I want to point out one subtle mistake, if I may be so pedantic. Where you say, "That means, in the original file after line 78 (= 75 + 3 lines of context) add two lines.", you should say "after line 77", because line 75 is itself one of the 3 lines of context, i.e. lines 75, 76 and 77 are the context. So it is actually immediately after line 77 (=75+2) where the new code will be added. So the new text "line1" will be on line 78 (if those 2 new lines were the only changes/diffs.)  You get the point I'm sure.

Comment: @Will, thanks, fixed.

Comment: This is called a diff unified format. One should not rely on the contextual lines, before/after since it's not always 3, it can be any number.
In [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) opinion this can be summerized as:
`@@ -l,s +l,s @@`: this is a **hunk range information** which contains **2 hunk ranges**.
The one with `-` is the original file.
The one with `+` is the new file.
`l` indicates the starting line number, `s` is the sum of the contextual lines and deleted lines (for the first hunk) and the contextual lines and addition lines (for the second hunk). That's it.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the Wikipedia article, the `,s` parts can be omitted in which case they mean just one line, so `@@ 1 1,20 @@` is equivalent of `@@ 1,1 1,20 @@`

Answer (score 23):

> I wonder what does the four numbers mean?

**Let's analyze a simple example**

The format is basically the same the `diff -u` unified diff.

We start with numbers from 1 to 16 and remove 2, 3, 14 and 15:

```
diff -u <(seq 16) <(seq 16 | grep -Ev '^(2|3|14|15)$')
```

Output:

```
@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@
 1
-2
-3
 4
 5
 6
@@ -11,6 +9,4 @@
 11
 12
 13
-14
-15
 16
```

`@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@` means:

- `-1,6` means that this piece of the first file starts at line 1 and shows a total of 6 lines. Therefore it shows lines 1 to 6.

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  ```

  `-` means "old", as we usually invoke it as `diff -u old new`.
- `+1,4` means that this piece of the second file starts at line 1 and shows a total of 4 lines. Therefore it shows lines 1 to 4.

  `+` means "new".

  We only have 4 lines instead of 6 because 2 lines were removed! The new hunk is just:

  ```
  1
  4
  5
  6
  ```

`@@ -11,6 +9,4 @@` for the second hunk is analogous:

- on the old file, we have 6 lines, starting at line 11 of the old file:

  ```
  11
  12
  13
  14
  15
  16
  ```
- on the new file, we have 4 lines, starting at line 9 of the new file:

  ```
  11
  12
  13
  16
  ```

  Note that line `11` is the 9th line of the new file because we have already removed 2 lines on the previous hunk: 2 and 3.

Comment: More clear, thanks.

Comment: To the point and very clear. Awesome! This answer actually explains the format without complicating the numbers with a reference to context of the output.

Answer (score 5):

Summary:

- Assume `git diff` will output [0-3] lines of context [before/after] [first/last] changes

@@ -[`original file's number of first line displayed`],[`context lines + removed lines`] +[`changed file's number of first line displayed`],[`context lines + added lines`] @@